# Whats the possibility of one updating a database field with a form having a drop down without changing the value of the drop down field

Tags: php, html

Lets say i input data into a mysql database using a drop down like:

```
<div>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"></div>
<div>
  <select name="position" id="position" type="text">
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>                        
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

With a normal text field, i can simply include the value field to show on the form the initially entered data in the table. And change that so when i submit form, it updates the related field.

```
<div>
  <select name="position" id="position" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_position['Position']; ?>>
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>                        
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

So assuming i do not want to update the field relating to the drop down, how do i it? Because what happens is, once i submit the form without selecting any option from the drop down, it picks the first option from the list which is the "Select" option and uses that to update the related field in the database.

Comment: keep everything as it is in your second html snippet, just add `disabled` attribute to first option.

Comment: @marmeladze if i add disabled to the first option, then it just goes on to pick the second option. What i was thinking is that, if i do not select an option from the drop down, then it should not update the field in the database

Comment: Why don't you make the initially entered data the selected one?

Comment: Other possibility is to give "Select" the value -1 and check on the server-side if you should update or not (`if($_POST['position']>0)`).

Comment: @Jeff Your first suggestion worked. All i did was just change the value of the option "select" to value="<?php echo $row_position['Position']; ?>

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your input.

Comment: And thanks @marmeladze for your contribution also.

Comment: Yes, this solution will work, but it's a bit hacky.... and not very user-firendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest at least two steps to make it user-friendly and achieve your goals:

First, make the initially entered selection selected if available:

```
<?php 
    $positions = Array("A", "B", "C");
?>
<div>
  <select name="position" id="position">
      <option value="-1">Select</option>
      <?php
      foreach($positions as $v) {
         $selected = ($row_position['Position']===$v) ? "selected" : "";
         echo "<option value='$v' $selected>$v</option>";
      }
      ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

And on the receiving php-script check if you've received a valid option, otherwise send error-message:

```
<?php
//other stuff...

if($_POST['position']>0) {
    // save that value
} else {
   // send error to user
}
// even more stuff..
?>
```

*Notes*: in select tag there is no `type=text` nor a `value=anything` available.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion and it works pretty fine. Will use your suggestion as that is better than my work around the issue. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are fetching dropdown options from database.

***Note***: Array keys, variables are only for demonstration purposes. This may differ from your actual records.

```
<div>
  <select name="position" id="position">
    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
    <option value="<?= $option['position'] ?>" <?php if($option['position'] == $current_record['position']) { echo "selected"; }  ?>> <!-- e.g. $option['id'] -->
      <?= $option['name'] ?>
    </option>                        
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have done that has solved the issue was to simply add the value from the database to the selectedoption or the first option field. So by default without changing the drop down, the first option with the value from the database is selected. And so there would be no change.

```
<div>
<div><?php echo $row_position['Position']; ?></div>
  <select name="position" id="position">
    <option value="<?php echo $row_position['Position']; ?>Select to Change</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>                        
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This gives a simple or straight forward solution to the problem.
Will still try the other suggestions to see how it all plays out. Thanks guys.

Comment: As I said in my comment, this will work but is hacky and not user-friendly, because you don't show what the user has selected before. Still I'm glad I could help. (and get rid of type=text and value in select-tag. they don't exist there)

Comment: @Jeff I included a div above to show what the user had stored before.

Comment: Will also try your suggestion. Thanks again. will let you know if i have any issues with your suggestion.